# Preg_replace call function in same class?

Tags: php, function, object, preg-replace

How can preg_replace call a function in the same class?

I have tried the following:

```
<?php

defined('IN_SCRIPT') or exit;

class Templates {

    protected $db;

    function __construct(&$db) {
        $this->db = &$db;
        $settings = new Settings($this->db);
        $gamebase = new Gamebase($this->db);
        $this->theme = $settings->theme_id;
        $this->gameid = $gamebase->getId();
    }

    function get($template) {
        $query = $this->db->execute("
            SELECT `main_templates`.`content`
            FROM `main_templates`
            INNER JOIN `main_templates_group`
                ON `main_templates_group`.`id` = `main_templates`.`gid`
            INNER JOIN `main_themes`
                ON `main_themes`.`id` = `main_templates_group`.`tid`
            WHERE
                `main_themes`.`id` = '".$this->theme."'
            &&
                `main_templates`.`name` = '".$template."'
        ");
        while ($templates = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $content = $templates['content'];

            // Outcomment
            $pattern[] = "/\/\*(.*?)\*\//is";
            $replace[] = "";

            // Call a template
            $pattern[] = "/\[template\](.*?)\[\/template\]/is";
            $replace[] = $this->get('header');

            $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $content);
            return $content;
        }
    }
}
```

But that just comes out with the following error:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@site.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

As soon as I outcomment this:

```
// Call a template
$pattern[] = "/\[template\](.*?)\[\/template\]/is";
$replace[] = $this->get('header');
```

Then it works. But i need it to run a function.

And actually I don't need it to run the function with the `header` value in, I need the content between `[template]` and `[/template]` to be in the function.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [callback type in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).

Comment: So should the `$replace[]` be something like this? `$replace[] = array_map($double, "$1");`, and then above it I should have this to run my function? `$call_a_template = function($a) { $this->get($a); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your script might be entering an infinite loop. If you look in your get function, you're calling this:

```
$replace[] = $this->get('header');
```

So in the middle of a get call, you're pulling in the header. This then executes the exact same function which will itself pull in the header, over and over, over and over. You might want to disable this line for when `$template` is 'header':

```
while ($templates = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {   

   $content = $templates['content'];

   // If this is the header, stop here
   if ($template == 'header') 
      return $content;

   // Rest of loop...
}
```

If you want to perform regular expressions, add this after the while loop:

```
if ($template == 'header') {
   $pattern = "/\[template\](.*?)\[\/template\]/is";
   $replace = 'WHATEVER YOU WANT TO REPLACE IT WITH';
   return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $templates['content']);
}
```

Comment: Well, it will not run the same. As the content of the `header` template from the databse doesn't include `[template]...[/template]`, which is the content which should trigger this function.

Comment: `$this->get` is still being invoked when you define the `$replace` parameter, which will start an infinite loop

Comment: You was right. I just tried it out. But what if I need that to also look for `[template]...[/template]`, as in the `header` there could be a `[template]menu[/template]`

Comment: Just do a similar preg_replace on that header template - see updated answer

Comment: Okay. Thanks. That fixed my problem :) Now, the only problem is to make it put in the real value from the `$1` into the `$replace[] = $this->get('header');`. So that it is not always just header. Put when I put in `"$1"`, it just comes out as `$1`, when it should put the content of `[template]...[/template]`. Any ideas?